# Iteract through __NSSingleObjectArrayI in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm getting the below response and how do I iterate or get the values?

```
<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600002edeea0>(
{
    link = "<null>";
    ValueG = "%";
    ValueT = 1;
    ValueV = "5.00";
    ValueS = "%";
    ValueGTX = 1;
    ValueGT = "5.00";
    ValueZH = 1;
    time = 30;
    UG = “test”;
    ValueSFS = "%";
    ValueFT = 1;
    ValueSFV = "5.00";
    SID = “000”;
    SN = Test;
    ST = "";
    ValueTV = "10.00";
    "__type" = “WSDInfo”;
}
)
```

This is how I tried to get the value, but it is throwing the following error `Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'NSDictionary *'`

```
    self.valuesInfo = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:self.valueType.storeInfoClass
                                       fromJSONDictionary:JSON
                                                    error:NULL];
NSDictionary *storeInfoDict = JSON;
        if (storeInfoDict.count != 0) {
                    for (int i=0; i <= storeInfoDict.count; i++){
                        NSString *ValueG = storeInfoDict[i][@"ValueG"];
                    }
                }
```

Below is the response from postman. In the code, "d" is removed by the JSONResponseSerializer

```
{
    "d": [
        {
            "__type": "WSDInfo",
            "SID": “000”,
            “SN”: “Test”,
            “ST”: "",
            "UG": “Test”,
            "time": "30",
            "ValueTV": "10.00",
            "ValueG": "%",
            "ValueV": "5.00",
            "ValueT": "1",
            "ValueSFS": "%",
            "ValueGT": "5.00",
            "ValueGTX": "1",
            "ValueS": "%",
            "ValueSFV": "5.00",
            "ValueZH": "1",
            "ValueFT": true,
            "link": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How is `storeInfoDict` declared?

Comment: What you printed is a `NSArray` (optimized for handling Single objects), but treat it as a `NSArray` instance. Inside there is a `NSDictionary`. But I guess, by the name and the error that `storeInfoDict` is declared as a `NSDictionary`. Well, it has only the name of it, because as saiid, it's in fact a `NSArray`.

Comment: @Willeke It is stored as NSDictionary

Comment: It's declared as a `NSDictionary` but the value at the end of the pointer is not a `NSDictionary`, it's a `NSArray`. Why? How did you get that value?

Comment: @Larme I have updated the post. You can see how I'm getting the value and also self.valuesInfo is returning nil

Comment: @Larme I have also provided the postman response

Comment: That's not how you enumerate a `NSDictionary`, you are enumerating like it was a `NSArray`. Look how to enumerate a `NSDictionary` first. Then, the value will be a `NSArray`, enumerate it too, and then acsess the valueG.